# UWP inherit from a class inherited from UserControl

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I am porting a Silverlight application to UWP Windows 10 app.

Large part of it has controls, inherited from a class, which inherits from UserControl.

```
base:
public abstract class PartBase : UserControl, IPart, IDisposable

concrete:
public sealed partial class MyPart : PartBase 

its XAML:
<local:PartBase
```

I get compilation error : The name "PartBase" does not exist in the namespace ..

**Is inheritance permitted in UWP ?**

Comment: inheritance is off topic on SO ? nice. how old are you son?

Comment: How do you define the namespace `local` in MyPart's XAML?

Comment: local represents the namespace where the PartBase is defined. so all is fine. see my comment on the @bart answer - it is more probable a VS 2017 bug. it works in a test app but not in the "main" app, if I remove "abstract" it works there too.. not right.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if you're not using the `clr-namespace` instead of `using` in it's declaration.

Comment: nope. its "using"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work. I've created your abstract base class and a new control based on that class.

```
<local:PartBase
    x:Class="UWPTest.Controls.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPTest.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Button>Test</Button>
    </Grid>
</local:PartBase>
```

Double check that the `xmlns:local="using:UWPTest.Controls"` is correct with the namespace `PartBase` is declared in. Then rebuild your solution and the error should go away (you will see the error if you don't rebuild).

On a page (e.g. MainPage) I can simply use the control:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWPTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:UWPTest.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <controls:MyUserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Note the `xmlns:controls` pointing to the correct namespace. The designer will also give an error until you rebuild the app.

Everything builds here and the application runs, so if you still have the error after double checking all namepace declarations you'll have to put a repro online so we can check what else goes wrong.

Comment: yes it looks like VS2017 bug. I can do what I intend to in a test project but not in my application.. however if I remove "abstract" from the base class definition it works..

Comment: Good news that you can move forward. Don't forget to post a quick bug report so Microsoft can look into it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea why it works in a sample app and not in the real app.. And Ms would want to reproduce.